# Getting custom viewcell item attributes

Tags: c#, xamarin, tableview, xamarin.forms

Goal - To cycle through a Tableview and obtain the input field type and value, ignoring label. The view is entirely based in c# code as the tableview will vary constantly.

So far in a for each look I can cycle through to the point of:

```
var x = (object)myViewCellInputItem[0];
```

For now I have set up a textview which has two elements, label and entry. The entry object I can obtain in var x as above.

Goal: Get the "Text" attrtibute.

```
Entry ent = (Entry)x;
string text = ent.Text;
```

The code above achives it. What I am face with is other Views such as DatePicker etc.

I was considering:

```
private string GetProperty(object XamarinObj)
{     
    string output;
    Type t = XamarinObj.GetType();

    if (t == typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Entry))
    {
        Entry ent = (Entry)XamaninObj;
        return ent.Text.ToString();
    }
    else if {
        .... repeat for other types    
    }
}
```

A unhelpful friend suggested to use Linq to query x to find "Text", "Items", "Date" etc but wouldn't show me how!

Your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

Well after much searching this is the route I went down. I can obtain all View/Text/Cell data I wish across all three platforms.